# Heroku and multer

Tags: node.js, heroku, web-applications, multer

I made a webapp that lets you upload a file to the server using multer. It works like it should when the server is run locally, but when I deployed it on Heroku, it seems I ran into a 500 internal server error.

Has anyone dealt with this before?

What are the options?

Webapp is here: https://dupefinder.herokuapp.com/

Github repo is here: https://github.com/ExtDASH/herkodeploy

```
2018-09-19T19:38:48.310177+00:00 app[web.1]: POST /uploads 500 148 - 181.170 ms
2018-09-19T19:38:48.310830+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'uploads/csv1537385928295.csv'
2018-09-19T19:38:48.311255+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/uploads" host=dupefinder.herokuapp.com request_id=ff1aaa34-f36c-49cf-bd4e-4a936fb48a2c fwd="24.52.32.175" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=188ms status=500 bytes=404 protocol=https
```

and here is the console error in the browser:

```
main.js:146 POST https://dupefinder.herokuapp.com/uploads 500 (Internal Server Error)
reader.onload @ main.js:146
load (async)
readFile @ main.js:131
invoker @ vue.js:2029
Vue.$emit @ vue.js:2538
click @ VBtn.ts:108
invoker @ vue.js:2029
fn._withTask.fn._withTask @ vue.js:1828
```

I'm using an `XMLHttpRequest` POST request:

```
readFile: function(){
        const input = document.querySelector('#myFile')
        const reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onload = function() {
            let csvfile = new Blob([reader.result], { type: 'text/csv' })
            app.uploadingFile = true

            const form = new FormData()
            let sendName = input.files[0].name.split(/\W+/g)

            form.append('Ncsv', csvfile, `${sendName[0]}.csv`)
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
            xhr.open('POST', '/uploads', true)
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(this.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status == 200) {
                    form.delete('Ncsv')
                }
            }
            xhr.send(form)

        }
        reader.readAsText(input.files[0])
```

which goes to an `app.post` route in my `server.js` file:

```
const express = require('express')
const connect = require('connect')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const fs = require('fs-extra')
const multer = require('multer')
const getRouter = require('./routes/ourNums')
const nFs = require('./fileSchema.js')
const namesRouter = require('./routes/namesRouter.js')
const computeRouter = require('./routes/computeRouter.js')

// const uploadRouter = require('./routes/uploadRouter') unused for now
const filesRouter = require('./routes/filesRouter')
const path = require('path')



const app = express()

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    fs.ensureFile(file)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('done')
     }
    cb(null, __dirname+'/uploads')
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    var newName = file.originalname.split(/\W+/g)
    var fullName = `${newName[0]}${Date.now()}.csv`
    cb(null, fullName)
},
})



var upload = multer({ storage: storage })

app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }))
app.use(morgan('tiny')) //watching for changes
// app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/client/index.html`))

app.post('/uploads', upload.single('Ncsv'), function (req, res, next) {
var fileName = req.file.filename
nFs.create({
    name: fileName
})
.then(data => res.status(200).send())
.catch(e => {
    req.error = e
    console.log(e)
    next()
})
})
```

before, I didn't use `fs` for anything (and as you can see here, `fs.ensureFile` isn't doing anything to fix the 500 error), I just included it to begin with so I could play around with it. Running the server locally, this works. I click my upload button on my client and it sends whatever file i selected as a blob, runs it through multer, and creates the file in a `/server/uploads/` directory

Edit: I just tried using `multer.memoryStorage()` and got the same 500 internal server error.

Comment: Please run `heroku logs` and find all errors around the HTTP 500 error. [Edit] your question and include that output here. If you select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K it will be formatted as code.

Comment: @Chris done. sorry about that.

Comment: It seems to just not be uploading or creating the file.

Comment: How are you doing the file upload? (Please add that to your question too—we generally won't go off-site to view code. Questions should be self-contained.)

Comment: @Chris done. again I apologize about that.

Comment: No need to apologize :-). It takes time to learn all the rules. Do you need these uploads long-term, or just short-term so you can do some processing on them?

Comment: Thanks :) first non-toxic commit i've gotten on stackoverflow in a while. I would like them to be kept long term, but short term works aswell..I think it would be better if they were kept longterm though.

Comment: im starting to get this feeling that using multer while running a local webapp is okay, but when the web app is deployed, using multer isn't what you should do, and rather use amazon S3..

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. The community is taking steps to become more welcoming. Hopefully you see fewer negative comments as you continue to use the site. Anyway, I'm not familiar with multer but I think you should be able to store files temporarily with it. Long-term storage is another story; please see my answer. And yes, if S3 is something you're already considering, it's a great fit here.

Comment: I just updated my answer to reference a library that might help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure why your uploads aren't being saved; you should be able to save them temporarily.

But this won't work long-term. [Heroku's filesystem is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem): any changes you make will be lost the next time your dyno restarts, which [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) (at least once per day).

Heroku [recommends storing uploads on something like Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3). Here's [a guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node) for doing it specifically with Node.js.

Once you've stored your files on S3 you should be able to retrieve them using an appropriate library or possibly over HTTP, depending on how you've configured your bucket.

If you still wish to use `multer`, check out [`multer-s3`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3).