# Multer doesn't save images

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku, multer

I'm using multer to save images files , it's all working great on my local host , but when I upload to heroku it doesn't save images, it also doesn't give me any errors , it gives me a response with the path to the - assumingly saved - image . But it's not actually saved.
This is the server logs

```
2020-06-05T17:40:10.380456+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/createPost" host=[My domain].herokuapp.com request_id=52523c79-a904-45cb-b657-9937d2b2b5fb fwd="154.237.170.96" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=482 protocol=http
2020-06-05T17:40:17.059624+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/createPost" host=[My domain].herokuapp.com request_id=4a87c2cb-6278-4733-9f0f-9b886a8f6d6a fwd="154.237.170.96" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6145ms status=201 bytes=824 protocol=http
```

What could the problem be ? 
thanks.

Comment: Simple questions first, do you have writing permissions to that path?

Comment: How do I know if I do ? , Is this configured via Heroku ?

Comment: From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52414725) it's not recommended to store files on heroku, as it's ephemeral and you will lose your files

Comment: did you tried adding a check in file upload like if folder exists upload else create folder then upload.

Comment: @thammada does this mean if I try any other webhosting provider it will work ?

Comment: @LogicBlower folder already exists

Comment: @OmarZahir it depends on the hosting solution, if you have virtual machines you will generally have access and control to everything. Heroku dynos are managed instances, you got less control but it's more simple to setup. The recommended way using s3 is not hard to setup, maybe you could give it a try.

Comment: I will give it a try , thank you